# can we changed pmkg installer file extension

Tags: macos, cmd, installation, packagemaker, mpkg

I am new in mpkg installer. when we create a mpkg installer from GUI it also create a .pmdoc workspace. where the file extension is .xml.
my question is that can we change the files file extension as txt or other format.

if yes is it possible to create mpkg installer to use these file. because i am not able to change files in pmdoc using command line.

Comment: Why do you want to change file extension?.pmdoc is user for creating package.

Comment: actually i want make creation of mpkg installer automatic. but using command line option of pmdoc i am not able to change my files(located inside contents). is any command line option to change file using command line. because after every build of my driver i need to change the file manually .